# Getting a type representation of a partially open generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to get a representation of a partially open generic type in C#, for example `IDictionary<string,>`.

What I have tried:

```
typeof(IDictionary<string,>)
```

I get: Partially opened type is not permitted in 'typeof' expression compile error.

```
typeof(IDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string))
```

I get: ArgumentException (The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition. Parameter name: instantiation)

Why I want to do this:

I have a number of scenarios where I need to check if a class I have implements an interface, but in several cases I know that some of the generic type parameters have to be specific (i.e. I want something that implements a dictionary with string keys but I don't care about the value type). I realize there are a number of other ways I could do this (for example, by providing an array of necessary generic parameter types to my method). But in looking at the problem I got curious if there is a way to specify partially open / partially closed generic types, hence the question.

Comment: can't you work with something like `Dictionary<string, T>`

Comment: As an option you could create DummyGenericArgument class and use it as an empty generic argument.

Comment: @AD.Net well, that is what I am asking - is there a way to get a type object that represents Dictionary<string, T>, where T is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that could answer to your problem:

```
class CustomDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<string, TValue>
{
}
```

And this should work:

```
typeof(CustomDictionary<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string))
```

Comment: That isn't quite what I was after, but actually, it does seem possible. If I define interface StringDict<T> : IDictionary<string, T> then the implemented inferface list of the StringDict<T> includes IDictionary<string,T>

Comment: That's the idea. :)

Comment: The problem is I would need to implement a (useless) interface for each thing I wanted to check, i.e. if I wanted to check if class Q implements IDictionary<string, T> I'd need a IStringDicChecker<T> : IDictionary<string, T>, then I would need to get the interfaces implemented by typeof(IStringDicChecker<>) and then I would need to find the one where the generic version is IDictionary<,>. Which is all doable, but I'd need to add a new interface to check IDictionary<int, T>, and so on.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need an interface for each type, since it's a generic one. And if `Q` implements `IStringDict<Something>`, you know for sure that `Q` implements `IDictionary<string, Something>`. Because you can make `IStringDict<T> : IDictionary<string, T>`. You don't have to check for `IDictionary` anymore, but for `IStringDict` instead.

Comment: Right. But if I want to check IDictionary<int, T>, I need a new interface. Or if I want to check IMyCustomInterface<T1, T2, T3> for IMyCustomInterface<string, any, any> I would need a new interface.

Comment: Yes. But you could have something like in the answer linked for the duplicate, a container to modify the `string` part. Anyway, when you get into generics with unknow number of parameters, you will have to make several interfaces to manage all these possibilities.